# Long-term present in a form of cryptocurrency for newborn

Tags: cryptography, paper-wallet, storage

Lets go...

I am relatively new to to world of crypto. Have some experience with Binance, last few weeks. My friend had a son, and I want to give him a little different present - crypto investment in a box. I was looking buy him Cardano or Bitcoin of some value, **and put all the info needed to reclaim all of that crypto in 18 years time. Is it possible to have all-non binary information for him to retrieve crypto, *in a form of paper/wood or physical*.???**

I am not an expert, so I would like to ask you. In year 2039, could you retrieve paper information to real Bitcoin or Cardano, and do you need third party information like **some kind of wallet or something that will maybe vanish in 10, 20 years**. Please only people who know this world very well , respond! Thank you!

Comment: Paper wallet is discouraged. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet.

Comment: Thanks, so it seams digital ones-and-zeroes are only way to go...

Answer (score 3):

I would get a wallet to generate a BIP-39 seed phrase, stamp the seed phrase onto durable metal, send money to the wallet and destroy the wallet, deleting all data.

Comment: Is this a metal paper wallet?

Comment: @Mercedes, most of the [problems associated with paper wallets](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Paper_wallet) don't apply to seed-phrases punched into metal and which are intended to be used to recreate a hierarchical deterministic wallet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to be timebound then suggestions in other answers like passing mnemonic phrases, paper wallets etc would be great. One nifty solution you can look at is - https://opendime.com/ (I am no way promoting their product, so pls look at it yourself).  According to my study, This comes close to a physical version of Bitcoin, which can be given to someone.

If you really want it to time bound like he should be able to retrieve only after 18 years then you will have to rely upon bit more than just the seed phrases. You will have to create a pay to script address and send coins there. I am still learning how to easily create that, may be more knowledgeable folks here can help.

Answer (score 0):

1. BIP 39 passphrase as suggested by RedGrittyBrick with derivation path printed on a paper
2. Descriptor based paper wallets: https://bitcoindevkit.org/blog/2021/03/descriptor-based-paper-wallets/
3. Hardware wallets or backup solutions like https://cypherock.com
4. Time locks and multisig can be used however I would avoid if not a power user and the goal is to gift, store and use later